# Allow Outlook VBA to run when item selected in explorer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I have code to pop a message up if I hit Reply rather than ReplyAll when responding to a certain customer.
I got it to run when I have the email open in the active window but not in the explorer pane.
I suspect I need a bit more code run on startup to set up for both possibilities.
The GetCurrentItem (from slipstick) allows either to be used to get the mailitem info but it does not fire from the explorer pane.

```vb
Dim WithEvents insp As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents mailItem As Outlook.mailItem

' This is called on Outlook startup
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set insp = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

' This is called when a new Inspector is created.
Private Sub insp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

' Called when you press Reply
Private Sub mailItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim strReplyAddress As String
    Dim strtest As String
    Dim olReply As mailItem
    
    ' enter the email address of your most valued customer here
    strReplyAddress = "name@domain.com" 

    Set mailItem = GetCurrentItem() ' should allow code to run in explorer or inspector

    ' this checks the reply email address.
    ' If it is the most valued customer then
    '  we need to see if Reply All has been selected!

    If mailItem.Sender.Address = strReplyAddress Then
    ' check how many recipients.
    ' If it is greater than one then it is not being sent to ALL!!

        If mailItem.Recipients.Count > 1 Then

            msg = "You are replying to Sender Only" & vbCr & vbCr & _
              "Do you want to Reply to All?" _
              & vbCr & vbCr & "Click Yes to SEND to ALL" & vbCr & vbCr & _
              "Click No to reply to SENDER ONLY" & vbCr & vbCr & _
              "Click Cancel to CANCEL THIS EMAIL"

            result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNoCancel, "Reply Check")
            If result = vbYes Then
                Cancel = True
                Set olReply = mailItem.ReplyAll

                ' this displays the email for sending with all recipients added.
                olReply.Display 
            End If

            If result = vbCancel Then
                Cancel = True ' this stops the email from being created.
            End If

        ' by default if you click NO the code ends up here
        '  without modification and displays the email
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not know much about Outlook develop issue, maybe you could get more information from the dedicated forum for Outlook for developers. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev

Answer (score 1):

This is how to trigger a selection change event.

```vb
Dim WithEvents insp As Inspectors
Dim WithEvents mailItem As mailItem

Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Explorer

' This is called on Outlook startup
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set insp = Inspectors
    Set myOlExp = ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()

    ' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Explorer.SelectionChange
    ' there can be an array out of bounds error when changing folders
    ' uncomment if an error occurs
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set mailItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    'Debug.Print mailItem.subject

    ' Remove error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub

' This is called when a new Inspector is created.
Private Sub insp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.currentItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set mailItem = Inspector.currentItem
    End If
End Sub


' Called when you press Reply
Private Sub mailItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim strReplyAddress As String
    Dim strtest As String
    Dim olReply As mailItem
        
    strReplyAddress = "name@domain.com" ' enter the email address of your most valued customer here
    
    ' this checks the reply email address.
    ' If it is the most valued customer then we need to see if Reply All has been selected!
    If mailItem.Sender.Address = strReplyAddress Then
    
    ' check how many recipients in Response
    '  if equal to one then not being sent to ALL!!
                
        Debug.Print Response.Recipients.count
        If Response.Recipients.count = 1 Then

            msg = "You are replying to Sender Only" & vbCr & vbCr & "Do you want to Reply to All?" _
            & vbCr & vbCr & "Click Yes to SEND to ALL" & vbCr & vbCr & _
            "Click No to reply to SENDER ONLY" & vbCr & vbCr & _
            "Click Cancel to CANCEL THIS EMAIL"

            result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNoCancel, "Reply Check")
            If result = vbYes Then
                Cancel = True
                Set olReply = mailItem.replyall
                olReply.Display 'this displays the email for sending with all recipients added.
                
            ElseIf result = vbCancel Then
                Cancel = True ' this stops the email from being created.
                
            End If

        End If ' by default if you click NO the code ends up here without modification and displays the email

    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had just about given up finding a solution.
Regards